# in codevision editor For category code like(region)

Tags: c, codevisionavr

In many language like java,c#,... , we use

```
    //region Variables
.
.
.
    //endregion
```

for category code.
what we use instead "region" in CodeVision editor.

Comment: "we use" ... pluralis majestatis? **I** do not (what does that actually mean?.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeVision there is no mechanism to do that exactly but I could do something similar with the following code:

```
//Your region name
{
    // Your code here
}
```

This way a little (-) minus sign will appear next to the open bracket then you can collapse it but you should consider that brackets make a scope so your variables will affect.